# Borrar todas las ramas excepto la master

Tags: git

En mi proyecto he creado muchas ramas. Después de una solicitud de fusión o combinación (*merge request*) borro la rama que fusioné con la master **en GitHub** pero la rama se queda mi laptop.

Yo sé que puedo borrarlas una por una, pero **¿existe alguna forma de borrar todas las ramas, excepto la master?**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En mi caso he usado esta instrucción:

```
$ git branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
```

intentalo y me cuentas!

No olvides tener un backup de tu proyecto!

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección.

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar las ramas que ya han sido fusionadas en la rama actual y que han sido eliminadas en el repositorio remoto:

```
git fetch -p && git branch -d `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`
```

A continuación se explica paso a paso lo que hace este conjunto de comandos:

- `git fetch -p` Obtiene los cambios más recientes desde el repositorio remoto, y elimina ("corta") las referencias a las ramas remotas que ya no existen.
- `git branch -vv` Lista las ramas de forma detallada, lo cual incluye información el vínculo entre las ramas locales y las referencias a las ramas remotas, así como el estado de las ramas remotas.
- `grep ': gone]'` Del listado anterior de ramas, filtra aquellas que contengan el texto ': gone]', es decir, aquellas ramas cuyas ramas remotas vinculadas ya fueron eliminadas. Estas ramas eliminadas poseen el estado gone.
- `awk '{print $1}` De la lista filtrada, obtiene la primera columna, la cual contiene el nombre de la rama local.
- `xargs` Convierte las filas de nombres de ramas en una cadena de una sola línea, separando el contenido de cada fila mediante un espacio en blanco.
- `git branch -d` Elimina las ramas listadas en el paso anterior. Al utilizar la d minuscula, se indica que no se forzará la eliminación de ramas, lo que previene que se eliminen ramas locales que no hayan sido combinadas (merged) a otras ramas.